# Select a file on an open Windows Explorer

Tags: vb.net

I have the following cod that will start a Windows Explorer with a file selected and maximize Explorer. It then will look for the Windows Explorer and minimize it. I did the maximize-minimize so that I would not have to do this manually (lazy, I know). I have this set up in my code to trigger only when the folder is not open. If it is open, then just run the minimize part. Here's the code:

```
If Not FolderIsOpen Then
    Dim curProcess As Process = New Process()
    With curProcess
        With .StartInfo
            .FileName = "explorer.exe"
            Dim MinimizeName As String = RegScoringWorkbookName.Replace(".xlsm", ".zip")
            .Arguments = String.Format("/select, ""{0}""", MinimizeName)
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        End With
        .Start()
    End With
    Thread.SpinWait(100000000)
    For Each IWindow As InternetExplorer In SHWindows
        If IWindow.Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
            Dim GetURIPath As New Uri(IWindow.LocationURL)
            If GetURIPath.LocalPath.ToLower.Equals(FolderName) Then
                ShowWindow(CType(IWindow.HWND, IntPtr), SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next IWindow
Else
    For Each IWindow As InternetExplorer In SHWindows
        If IWindow.Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
            Dim GetURIPath As New Uri(IWindow.LocationURL)
            If GetURIPath.LocalPath.ToLower.Equals(FolderName) Then

                'Code here to select the targeted file

                ShowWindow(CType(IWindow.HWND, IntPtr), SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next IWindow
End If
```

So, my question is, can Explorer be told to select a file on an already opened Windows Explorer?

Comment: Why would you need to select a file in a user interface (Windows Explorer) and then minimize that user interface so the user can't see it? It might be better to ask a question related to the task you're actually trying to accomplish (unless it's simply to annoy the user with Explorer maximizing and minimizing) - there's probably a much cleaner way to accomplish it.

Comment: Ken, the reason I wish to do this is my tool will be creating a lot of files. The tool will be used at a desk used by shift workers, and I want the user to have a Windows Explorer open with the most important file selected so they do not have to go digging in the Explorer\My Computer. The reason why I minimize it is because I want the user to see that the tool has completed. If i do not minimize, then they may not see it has completed. I have not been able to find many alternatives, so I have to humbly ask the gurus of StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 6):

You could just shell it out.

```
Dim i = Shell("explorer /select, C:\Folder\File.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

Comment: Classic! Really simple and smart.

Comment: What's the comma after select for?