# Click items in flow layout panel?

Tags: vb.net

I have some images in my flow layout panel that I want to click and open the directory of where the image is located. I'm not sure how to cast that on click. If I set the mouse click or click event of the flow layout panel clicking the panel will go to the directory, but I want it on clicking the image, any help is appreciated. Here's my code for adding and clicking the panel:

```
    private sub addpic()
         .......get picture and copy it on clipboard blah blah....

         Dim img as Image
         img = Clipboard.GetImage
         Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
         imageControl.Height = 100
         imageControl.Width = 100
         Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)
         Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(img)
         Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(96, 96, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
         imageControl.Image = myThumbnail

         myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(imageControl)
    end sub

    Private Sub myFlowLayoutPanel_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles myFlowLayoutPanel.MouseClick
    Dim path As String
    path = "c:\picture.jpg"
    Process.Start(path, "iexplorer.exe")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23895009/6144259

Comment: If the images are in PictureBoxes, you probably want to respond to picturebox clicks/double clicks, no?  And since an image is not a file name, you need some way to link a file name with it, like the `.Tag` property

Comment: Can you please show **how you are adding these picturebox's** to the `FlowLayoutPanel`? You can add a handler to each to call a method to process the event you want. Also you can add a `tag` object to each `PictureBox` that you can access in the method you are calling to do what you need.

Comment: Since you apparently already have the image loaded, it would be simple to provide your own Previewer using a second form with a PictureBox on a scrollable panel

Comment: @zaggler recheck post.

Comment: @Plutonix I don't want to have to open another form to view pictures, if someone wants to view the picture they can just click the picture to go straight to original file.

Comment: `AddHandler imageControl.MouseClick, AddressOf picturePreview_MouseClick` Now you can know which ctl was clicked (Sender), if the `blah blah` code deals with the filename, store it to the Tag so you know which one to open.  BTW, your code is leaking resources.

Comment: can you provide an answer to this post with a example thanks @Plutonix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023022/1070452  Part of creating the control is hooking it to an event handler, just add the line above to the loop.